# Python List To Dictionary - Without Value Overwrite

Tags: python, dictionary, key, append

```
Keys = [1,2,3]
Values = [["a",1],["b",2],["c",3],["d",1]]

Dictionary = dict.fromkeys(Keys)  

for d in Dictionary:
    for value in Values:
        if value[1] == d:
            # Add to dictionary
            Dictionary.update({d:value})
        # else
            # Do Nothing

print(Dictionary)
```

When I run this piece of code, it works fine until I look closer at the its output. I've noticed that because I wanted to add two 'values' to the 'Key' 1, it overwrites the first one added and leaves the last, here is the output:

```
{1: ['d', 1], 2: ['b', 2], 3: ['c', 3]}
```

I would like the values of key 1 to be both `['a',1]` AND `['d',1]`.

Comment: So: `{1: [['a', 1], ['d', 1]], ...}` then?

Comment: Yes that's what i'd want from the for loop

Comment: Dictionary keys are unique... so no...

Comment: Sorry im confusing myself, yes id like what you put first to be the output of the for loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) object.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from collections import defaultdict

values = [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3], ["d", 1]]
d = defaultdict(list)
for x, y in values:
    d[y].append([x, y])
```

Then you can access the key and values like a regular dict object.

```
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    print "{} {}".format(k,v)
```

Which outputs

```
1 [['a', 1], ['d', 1]]
2 [['b', 2]]
3 [['c', 3]]
```

Comment: Just a note: this is creating a new list for each item and not referencing the original list in `Values`. To do that keep the list packed and use index `0` as key.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to have multiple values for a single key is to wrap them in a further container, usually a list. You could do that like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

keys = [1,2,3]
values = [["a",1],["b",2],["c",3],["d",1]]

mydict = defaultdict(list)
for key in keys:
   mydict[key].extend(value for value in values if value[1] == key)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, you mean:

```
my_dict = {i:[] for i in Keys}

for a, b in Values:
    my_dict[b].append([a, b])
```